# How to access DOM in Firefox addon script?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I tried to use something like `document.forms` in Firefox-addon script but it doesn't work.

So, I need to manipulate DOM objects in Firefox-addon script such as forms, inputs... etc. How can I do that without using SDK?

Comment: Where is your script running? Or how are you invoking it?

Comment: It is a javascript file inside my Firefox plugin ".xpi" file.

Comment: A JavaScript file inside an xpi file won't execute just like that. Once again, how are you running it? Browser overlay? XPCOM component? SDK module?

Comment: Yes Browser overlay ".xul" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your comments, your code is running in the context of the browser window. This means that `document` refers to the document of the browser window, not the document that is loaded into it. The easiest way to get to the latter is using the [`window.content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.content):

```javascript
var contentDoc = content.document;
alert(contentDoc.forms.length);
```

This will give you only the current tab however. For the other tabs you can use the APIs provided by the [`<tabbrowser>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/tabbrowser) (accessible via the global `gBrowser` variable), e.g. to access the first tab:

```javascript
var contentDoc = gBrowser.browsers[0].contentDocument;
alert(contentDoc.forms.length);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt seem to be working for me? FF 44.0a2 Dev Edition. content.document doesnt return the DOM

Comment: @Irtza.QC: The question was about classic extensions executing in the context of the browser window. If you have an SDK extension or a bootstrapped extension things will be very different. In any case, you have to start considering E10S - meaning using content scripts / frame scripts / process scripts to access the DOM, depending on your environment. This answer pre-dates E10S and will soon be outdated.

Comment: if its not too much of a bother, could i ask you to look at a question of mine? Regarding something similar? https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/page-dom-in-pagemod-content-script/6199

Comment: @Irtza.QC: That question has nothing to do with the DOM access, only with the way you are trying to bootstrap Angular in your extension - and that's nothing I am familiar with.

Answer (score 4):

`document.forms` will not work, because `document` is not what you think it is: It is the top level browser (Firefox) window, and not the content in a tab.

A Firefox browser window can have multiple tabs, one of which is the active tab. The active tab [`<browser>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/browser) (which is the XUL element containing the actual content document) also has [a shortcut named `content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.content), e.g. `content.document.forms` will be a collection of forms in the *active* tab.
So you'll have to adjust your mental model here from

> `window` and `document` refer to a website

to

> `window` and `document` refer to the top-level browser window that may contain a lot of different websites.

The top-level window is more like a document containing multiple frames (the actual websites), really, but with a different APIs to access them.

So, e.g. when executing some action after the user pressed some add-on toolbar button, it might be enough to just use `content.document.forms` to get the forms of the currently active tab.

But using `content.` is often not enough: Add-ons would listen for page loads in tabs as the user navigates by adding appropriate event listeners to the [`<tabbrowser>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/tabbrowser) (`gBrowser`), which is the element containing all tabs. [MDN has some code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_page_load) for that and lots of other stuff.

Other add-ons add item(s) to the content context menu (`contentAreaContextMenu`) and [use the `popupshowing` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/PopupGuide/Extensions) to know what DOM node (and by this what `.ownerDocument` and content `window == .ownerDocument.defaultView`) is currently focused.

An important thing to always keep in mind: Your add-on code runs with full privileges, while websites of course do not. So be careful not to write insecure code. E.g. all forms of unbound `eval` are evil.